# Custom snippets with a specific behavior with a keybinding in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, customization, vscode-snippets

I am trying to insert a snippet `%>%` with a keybinding `Ctrl+Shift+M` in VS Code.

Example code:

```
data %>% select()
```

I am able to achieve this (**not totally happy**) with this setting in `keybindings.json`

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "Ctrl+Shift+M",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
          "snippet": " %>% "
        }
      }
]
```

In `RStudio` IDE whether I have **a** space after `data` or not, with the `Ctrl+Shift+M` keybinding, it only inserts a single space between `data` and `%>%`. See this:

[image]

However in the setting I have created in `keybindings.json` in VS Code, I am not able to limit space between `data` and `%>%` to only a single space. With my setting I will have **two spaces** in between. See this:

[image]

I read [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets), and [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization) but couldn't help.
How could I possibly limit the space to only a single space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is tricky to do what you want because vscode snippets just insert whether the cursor is - but you cannot delete something before the cursor.  It would be easy to do if you selected that prior word, like `data` in your case, but you probably don't want to do that.

But using a conditional replacement it is possible:

```
{
  "key": "Ctrl+Shift+M",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "${TM_CURRENT_WORD/(.*)/${1:? %>% :%>% }/}"
  }
},
```

This snippet looks at the `word` under the cursor when you trigger it.  If there is a word, like when the cursor is right after a word that counts, there will be a capture group 1.  If there is no word, like if you entered a space first and a space is considered a `word` apparently for the purposes of `TM_CURRENT_WORD`, there will be no capture group 1.

The replacement text is `${1:? %>% :%>% }` which is a conditional replacement which says: if there is a capture group 1, the case with no space, insert  `%>%`  with one leading and trailing space.  Else when capture group 1 so there already is a leading space, insert `%>%`   with no leading space but one trailing space.

Demo:

[image: demo of snippet with/without spaces]

The only case where it doesn't work as you wish is case 4 in the demo which is hopefully not a common use case for you - going back into text to insert your snippet.  It adds the extra space because with the cursor right before a word that is considered a `TM_CURRENT_WORD` and falls into capture group 1.  Otherwise I think the only solution to this use case would be an extension or require you to select that preceding word first.

Comment: Does the job for my use case. Would love to see a workaround for case 4 too. Thank you.